# JavaScript Memory Management (Info)

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks

What I am trying to work out is whether nullifying is always necessary. As I am having a few issues with Chrome. Say I have this code.

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype.MyFunction = function() {
    this.data = "foo";
}
var c = new MyClass();
c.MyFunction();
```

Now once that function is called it should be allowed to be GC but should the end of the function have `this.data = null`. Should this also be standard.

Comment: That code will throw a TypeError. Did you mean to instantiate `MyClass`?

Comment: here's a helpful article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-memleak/

Comment: Yeah I was writing the code in here and forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work. You should first create an instance of your class:

```
var c = new MyClass();
c.MyFunction();
```

because `MyFunction` is instance function.

Otherwise there's also `delete` operator ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and an [indepth analysis](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)), that is used to remove object members (but not objects themselves). Objects can therefore be garbage collected when there's no way to reference them any more, so

```
c = undefined;
```

should convince Javascript to garbage collect this object instance and release memory resources taken by it.

It is different if your object instance is instantiated this way:

```
c = new MyClass();
c.MyFunction();
delete c; // success
```

because `c` is this time a member of global (`window`) and can therefore be deleted from it.

Comment: My main issue is that I cannot remove the main class.

Comment: @Sam_Benne: Class or instance of your class?

Comment: Instance. Its a "Single Page App" So I need to keep the main instance but I can clear other smaller ones which I do.

Comment: @Sam_Benne: So what's the problem then? **Why** and **when** would you want to clear the main instance?

Comment: I haven't got a problem what I was trying to find out is whether the GC would clean out the vars that are generated in the function when it is not in use.